I have just updated my expo project and seem to have a little bit of an error. ERROR Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoImage', js engine: hermes
WARN  The native view manager required by name (ExpoImage) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: [ExpoBlurView].
ERROR  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoImage', js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

npx expo start -c
npx expo install expo-image
npx expo prebuild
They all did not help.

I tried for 3 hours, several different solutions. The final sequence that worked was the following:

deleted app from phone
deleted ios folder from app
npx expo prebuild
npx expo run:ios

There are a lot of other combinations of things I tried, but this ultimately worked. My best guess is that something in the ios folder wasn't being updated or installed after trying to add the expo-image package.
